# Error Controlador no encontrado, ajax con php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, namespace

El error es el siguiente:

**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Class "Controllers\CategoryController" not found in
C:\xampp\htdocs\pos\ajax\CategoriesAjax.php:15
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\pos\ajax\CategoriesAjax.php(23): Ajax\CategoriesAjax::ajaxEditarCategoria()
#1 {main}
thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\pos\ajax\CategoriesAjax.php** on line **15**

**ajax/CategoriesAjax.php**

```
<?php

namespace Ajax;

use Controllers\CategoryController;

class CategoriesAjax
{
   public $idCategoria;

   public static function ajaxEditarCategoria()
   {
        $item = "id";
        $valor = $_POST["idCategoria"];
        $respuesta = CategoryController::MostrarCategorias($item, $valor); // Line 15
        echo json_encode($respuesta);
   }
}

if (isset($_POST["idCategoria"])) {
    $categoria = new CategoriesAjax();
    $categoria->idCategoria = $_POST["idCategoria"];
    $categoria->ajaxEditarCategoria(); // Line 23
}
```

**controllers/CategoryController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Controllers;

use Models\Category;

class CategoryController
{
    public static function MostrarCategorias($item, $valor)
    {
        $tabla = "categorias";
        $respuesta = Category::MostrarCategorias($tabla, $item, $valor);
        return $respuesta;
    }
}
```

**models/Category.php**

```
<?php

namespace Models;

use Models\Conexion;
use PDO;

class Category
{
    public static function MostrarCategorias($tabla, $item, $valor)
    {
        if ($item != null) {
            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");
            $stmt->bindParam(":" . $item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->fetch();
        } else {
            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        }
    }
}
```

y el script que ejecuta el ajax es el siguiente:

```
$(".btnEditarCategoria").click(function () {
    var idCategoria = $(this).attr("idCategoria");
    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("idCategoria", idCategoria);
    
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax/CategoriesAjax.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function (respuesta) {
            $("#editarCategoria").val(respuesta["categoria"]);
            $("#idCategoria").val(respuesta["id"]);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
})
```

Estructura de carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando composer y tengo mi autoload cargando models, controllers y ajax respectivamente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien ejecute un "composer dump-autoload", pero el error persiste.
Donde estoy fallando?

Comment: es el include de la clase  CategoryController quiza el autoload no lo este integrando, igual falta informacion

Comment: Tambien probe poniendo un require, pero no funciono, que es lo que necesitas?, el include es de CategoryController?

Comment: composer dump-autoload solo agrega las clases de los paquetes instalados por composer, no las que tu creaste, para que funciones si o si deves agregar tus propias clases con includes individuales después del autoload, eso si no tiener una herramienta que ya lo haga por ti.

Comment: "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Controllers\\":"Controllers/",
            "Models\\":"Models/"
        }
    }
Este es mi composer.json donde puse el autoload psr-4

Comment: y la estrucctura o el arbol de carpetas de tu proyecto? recuerda que es standar psr-4 dice que debes tener un orden espesifico u una sintaxis de mayuscula asi como la considencia del nombre de la clase

Comment: Acabo de añadir la estructura y el composer.json

Comment: Nop, no encuentro errores, para mi todo esta formateado bien. si no sabes que mas puede ser, te recomendaría xdebug para ir al grano